# Combo-box loses selection after collection changes

Tags: wpf, combobox, observablecollection

I have a WPF combo box bound to an obvserable collection (OC):

```
    <ComboBox Name="cbCombination" ItemsSource="{Binding Combinations}" 
              SelectedIndex="0" />
```

Elsewhere, in the object set as data context:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Combination> Combinations { get; set; }
```

Combination overrides its ToString and everything is peachy: The combo-box's drop-down displays all Combination items in the Combinations OC. The combo-box's selection box displays the value of the first Combination.

Now, the data-context object has to change the values in its Combinations OC:

```
    var combinationsList = CombinationsManager.CombinationsFor(someParam);
    this.Combinations.Clear();
    foreach (var combination in combinationsList)
        this.Combinations.Add(combination);
    NotifyPropertyChanged(@"Combinations");
```

This causes the combo-box's selection box shows an empty string. (The drop-down is closed. However, when I make it drop down, it does show the correct new Combinations, so it *is* bound to the updated collection).

I tried to capture both SourceUpdated and (in my dispair) TargetUpdated events (thining of setting the SelectedIndex there), but my event handlers didn't get called!

So my question is: **How do I make a WPF ComboBox refresh the value of its selection-box when the observable collection it is bound-to changes?**

**Update**:

I've totally forgotten to mention, and I don't know whether it's important, but the combo-box is within a UserControl. The UserControl's XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="...CombinationsToolBar"
         .... mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<ToolBarTray Name="toolBarTray1" >
    <ToolBar Name="toolBar1">
        <ComboBox Name="cbCombination" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Combinations, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, 
                                                                     IsAsync=True}"
            SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="False"  
            SelectionChanged="CbCombinationSelectionChanged"
            SourceUpdated="CbCombinationSourceUpdated"
            TargetUpdated="CbCombinationTargetUpdated"></ComboBox>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

**In the UserControl's code** I have breakpoints on CbCombinationSelectionChanged, CbCombinationSourceUpdated and CbCombinationTargetUpdated.

The CbCombinationSelectionChanged fires once when the form containing the user control is first loaded. It is indeed called a second time when the Combinations collection is cleared, as @asktomsk said.

The source updated and target updated are not triggered - CbCombinationSourceUpdated and CbCombinationTargetUpdated are not called.

As the combo box is inside a usercontrol and the Combinations collection is within the view model, and as the view model doesn't have access to the combo box, **I have no opportunity to set the selected index of the combo unless the events fire**.

:(

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `this.Combinations.Clear();`
When you do it, it sets `SelectedItem = null` and `SelectedIndex = -1`

So you should set selection again. If you have an access to your ComboBox then just write this `cbCombination.SelectedIndex = 0;` after filling Combinations list.
Of course you can bind SelectedItem/SelectedIndex to some property in code behind too.

BTW
Also it is not required to call `NotifyPropertyChanged(@"Combinations");` after filling the collection because `Combinations` already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

**Update**

To detect that your *ObservableCollection* was changed, subscribe to *CollectionChanged* event in your *UserControl* code behind. Make sure that you subscribed **before** collection changed!

```
Combinations.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (cbCombination.Items.Count > 0)
        cbCombination.SelectedIndex = 0;
};
```

**Another suggestion**

Approach above is works when you do not need a smarter logic than just select zero index in combobox. 
But often you will need a more complex logic to select some item.  In this case you may add new property to your model:

```
public Combination SelectedCombination
{
    get{ return _selectedCombination; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCombination = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCombination");
    }
}
```

and bind this property to your combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbCombination" ItemsSource="{Binding Combinations}" 
          SelectedIndex="0" SelectedItem={Bindings SelectedCombination} />
```

In this case you can select any item when filling the Combinations collection and it will be automatically selected in combobox:

```
var combinationsList = CombinationsManager.CombinationsFor(someParam);
this.Combinations.Clear();
foreach (var combination in combinationsList)
    this.Combinations.Add(combination);

if (Combinations.Count > 0)
    SelectedCombination = Combinations[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but: I AM trying to set the selection again, but how? What should wakes up my code that will modify SelectedItem and / or SelectedIndex? My whole issue is that the combo box's SourceUpdated event doesn't fire!

Comment: It probably fires but your putting a breakpoint in the setter of Combinations and that won't fire if the collection changes, only if you assign it another collection. Use selectedindex, selectedvalue or selecteditem in code.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If it still not enough to solve the issue let me know.

Comment: In this case you may use CollectionChanged event of ObservableCollection class. Take a look at updated answer.