# Set selected item from another source

Tags: wpf

I have a combobox that has a content 'Male' and 'Female' with Tags 0 and 1 respectively. This is binded to a Medical.gender object. I am doing xml serialization so it give me 0 as output. How do i set the selected item back after deserialization. I'm using MVVM pattern?I have a combobox that has a content 'Male' and 'Female' with Tags 0 and 1 respectively. This is binded to a Medical.gender object. I am doing xml serialization so it give me 0 as output. How do i set the selected item back after deserialization. I'm using MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create property SelectedGender on your model class and bind this property to `SelectedItem` of your `ComboBox`.
I've described how to do it here ("Another suggestion" section):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815570/1088908